# Use Regex to remove characters between certain character

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to change a string so that anything in between the `*` character is removed

For example, the string `[xyz] - * remove this. . *  Abcd123` should become `[xyz] -   Abcd123`.

Another example:
`abc*def*ghi` should become `abcghi`

This is my code, I am trying to keep any character that is not `*` but  I don't think I am writing it correctly:

```
str = '[xyz] - * remove this. . *  Abcd123'

regex = re.compile('^(\*.*\*)+')
mo = regex.findall(str)
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\*(.*)\*', '', your_string)` -> `'[xyz] -   Abcd123'`?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

str = '[xyz] - * remove this. . *  Abcd123'

res = re.sub(r"\*[^\*]*\*", '', str)
```

Depending on what you need, you might want the `G` and `M` flags.

If you have several occurrences of `*....*`, this will take care of that. It will also make sure not to accidentally remove too much: for example, if you had `*....*....*`, this would consider only consecutive `*` for making pairs, not just looking at the first and the last `*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using regex. Try this:

```
str = 'abc*def*ghi'
replace = str[:(str.index('*'))] + str[(str.rfind('*') + 1):]
print(replace)
```

**.index()** -> Finds the first occurence of the character in a string 
**.rfind()** -> Finds the last occurence of a character in a string

Answer (score 2):

## First Method

```py
import re

s_1 = '[xyz] - * remove this. . *  Abcd123'
s_2 = 'abc*def*ghi'

reg = re.compile(r'\*.*\*')

print(reg.sub('', s_1))
print(reg.sub('', s_2))
```

**How does this regex work?**

This `\*` selects the asterisk `'*'`. Then we're selecting zero or more of everything within the two asterisk `'*'` using `.*`.

## Second Method

```py
s_1 = '[xyz] - * remove this. . *  Abcd123'
s_2 = 'abc*def*ghi'

print(''.join(s_1.split('*')[::2]))
print(''.join(s_2.split('*')[::2]))
```

Here we're basically splitting the code on `'*'` and then removing the part within the asterisks.